# How to stop default action of tab key in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML page multiple components exist and on pressing tab button, focus is set to some components (not in sequence). How do I stop tab from putting focus on any component on entire page ? Using outermost `div id` of html page can we block tab from putting focus on any component and on location bar as well ?

I have added jsfiddle [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/92Vxe/1/) as well where even I am not using tabindex but still focus is coming so kindly tell me how to disable tab  click.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
      event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
   }
});
```

Comment: Show code and what you tried.

Comment: @mplungjan I have not tried any code to stop tab from working but I am looking any example or hint with which I can proceed to disable tab on entire page because in my html page focus using tab click is not going in sequence , so it's difficult to predict order of focus. That's why I am looking for some example with which I can disable tab click on entire page

Comment: Kindly answer instead of down-voting my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried *below code* and its working fine in my **scenario** :

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) 
{
    var keycode1 = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode1 == 0 || keycode1 == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073092/chrome-not-allowing-tab-prevendefault?rq=1)

Comment: If you use TypeScript `if (e.key === "Tab") {`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some jQuery you can use to disable the tab key on the whole page.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
        event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
});
```

There may be some other ramifications of completely disabling the tab key that you may want to consider.

Comment: I have not used tabIndex in my HTML page , and focus is not moving in sequence except on textfields and its getting difficult to predict how focus is moving to any component. That's why I am looking for some option which disable tab click itself on entire page

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes , I am using jquery but using jQuery also I am not setting tabIndex

Comment: Updated the answer to just disable tab as you were looking for.

Comment: I tried your code as below : $("#home").on('keydown',function(){ //home is the outermost div
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
    event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
});                                                                  But still tab focus is coming. Is there anything which I am missing?

Comment: Did you try leaving it with $(document) so the whole page would be affected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56624/discussion-between-user2800089-and-jontewks).

Answer (score 0):

A little change try `keypress` instead of `keydown` and return false instead of `event.preventDefault();` 
Something like this

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
        return false; // stops its action
    }
});
```

Comment: In my posted fiddle , I tried but its not stopping tab from putting focus on buttons

Comment: @user2800089 its worked fine with this code 
Actually .on shud be removed from it 

`$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
        event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
})`

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this place so dont know How to answer in comments. I tried but it looks like a line not code
its worked fine with this code Actually .on shud be removed from it

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
        event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
})
```

Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92Vxe/3/) as well