# jQuery: How to disable tab key action on the regform with sliding mechanism

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the tab function where the tab key moves my regform slide when pressed a couple of times. How can I disable the tab for the regform area only.

Here's my html

https://jsfiddle.net/tbtt86u5/

I've seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073092/chrome-not-allowing-tab-prevendefault?rq=1) but it's not working on my situation. The tab is still working on the form where it slides every element.

I also tried using *tabindex* but it doesn't work on my side. The elements of the form is still sliding using tab.

```
<script> 
$('.steps').keydown(function (e) {
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
console.log(code);
if (code == 0 || code == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
First Name:<input type='text' />
<br/>
Last Name:<input type='text' />
```